# mySQLdb select formatting?

Tags: python, string-formatting, mysql-python

```
c.execute("select a, c, d from table")
for row in c:
    print(row)
```

Whenever I go this, the output is always:

```
('text field 1', 'text field 2', 'text field 3', 'text field 4')
```

I've been googling and cannot find the answer, is there a way I can make it like

```
text field 1, text field 2, text field 3, text field 4
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You printed the whole row, which is a tuple. To print it with a little formatting, you could use [`''.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
', '.join(row)
```

Comment: @RocketDonkey: I just did so! [-_-]~

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this

`from itertools import imap`

```
",".join(imap(str, row))
```